# .on method not working in Firefox 21.0

Tags: jquery, firefox, click

The following table will render, and the form will show, in Safari 5.1.9 and Chrome. The table will render but the form will not show in Firefox 21.0:

```
    $.each(json, function(index, value) {
        var posttimestamp = value.Post_timestamp;

    if(value.Post_timestamp != check) {
    var newpost='y';
        }
else {
    var oldpost='y';
        }

if(newpost) {
        $('#table2').append('<tr><td id="posttopic" colspan="2"><a href="forum24.php"    id=' + posttimestamp + '>' + topic + '</a></td><td></td></tr><tr><td id=' + "post" + posttimestamp + '>' + posttimestamp +'</td><td  id='+ "post" +posttimestamp+ 'colspan="3">' + post_txt + '</td><td>' + postuser + '</td><td>' + breed + '</td></tr>');

    }                       

      })

    $('td#posttopic').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var getid = event.target.id;
    alert(getid); // not working in Firefox

    $('div.form').show(); //not working Firefox

})
```

Comment: Identifiers should only appear once per document, `#posttopic` seems to be used multiple times. And what's `posttimestamp`?

Comment: I see that I am using the identifier #posttopic multiple times. I changed that to a class. posttimestamp is a variable created by iterating through the json object with the each method.

Answer (score 1):

.on() can be used for elements that are added after DOM is ready, such as:

```
$('table').on("click", 'td#posttopic', function(e) {
```

This way, the event is bound to any future elements (such as in your case) as well.

Comment: I added the selector as you suggest however 'div.form' is still not showing in Firefox.

Comment: @user2232681 I can't speak about that element, because I don't see it included. You'll have to show us your markup structure.